# Filter 2d array to keep all rows which contain a specific value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have a two dimensional haystack array like this:

```
[
    4 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
    1 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
    2 => [0, 1, 2, 3],
    3 => [0, 1, 2, 3]
]
```

Let's say that I have a search value of `$x = 10`.

How can I search in above array and get an **array index** which contains `$x`.

In my current example, subarrays with key **4** and **1** contain value of `$x` -- I need those 2 subarrays.

Comment: The idea is that you try something and ask when you have problems, although your user name indicates your effort.

Comment: @NigelRen, I tried already Bro,But i forgot to put my effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop then use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$array = array(...); // Your array
$x = 10;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (array_search($x, $value)) {
        echo 'Found on Index ' . $key . '</br>';
    }
}
```

Or if you need the arrays with those index

```
$array = array(...); // Your array
$x = 10;
$result = array(); // initialize results

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (array_search($x, $value)) {
        $result[] = $array[$key]; // push to result if found
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Just note that `array_search()` may return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `false`. To be safe, use `if (array_search($x, $value) !== false) {`

Comment: The use of `array_search()` is not reliable as Goma mentioned.  Also, because the actual key is not of any value for this task, the most appropriate function to call is `in_array()` because it more simply returns a `bool` type value (which is all that `array_filter()` needs). Also, `$array[$key]` is more simply accessed via `$value`.  `$key` is an unneeded declaration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to keep only the array that contains the value you want:

```
$array = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 10],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
];

$x = 10;
$out = array_filter($array, function($row) use($x) {
    return in_array($x, $row);
});
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 10
        )
)
```

In modern PHP (from PHP7.4), "arrow function" syntax can be used:

```
$x = 10;
var_export(
    array_filter($array, fn($row) => in_array($x, $row))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use as well `in_array`

```
$array = array(); // Your array
$x = 10;
$result = array(); // initialize results

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($x, $value)) {
        $result[] = $array[$key]; // 
    }
}

print_r($result)
```

Comment: `$array[$key]` is more simply accessed via `$value`.  `$key` is an unneeded declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_search() function to search the value in array..

Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

For Exp:

```
$x = 10; // search value 
$array = array(...); // Your array 
$result = array(); // Result array 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
{ 
   if (array_search($x, $value)) 
   { 
      $result[] = $array[$key]; // push the matched data into result array.. 
   }
}
```

print_r($result);

Comment: The use of `array_search()` is not reliable as Goma mentioned.  Also, because the actual key is not of any value for this task, the most appropriate function to call is `in_array()` because it more simply returns a `bool` type value (which is all that `array_filter()` needs). Also, `$array[$key]` is more simply accessed via `$value`.  `$key` is an unneeded declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_search();`

doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: You could Iterate through the array