# PHP search an array value inside an array in one line

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP 7.4. I have this array :

```
$sections = [
    'sectionOne' => [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'hello',
    ],
    'sectionTwo' => [
        'yo',
        'heya',
    ],
];
```

I'd like to build a function to return the section of the received array value

```
public function getSectionByValue($value) {
    return ...
}
```

If the value is `bar` then I'll get `sectionOne`. If the value is `yo` then I'll get `sectionTwo` etc...

How can I do to search an array value inside an array ? It is possible to do this in one line ?

Comment: Use a loop that calls `in_array()` in each nested array until it finds a match.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in one line. There's no built-in function for searching in nested arrays.

Comment: array_filter?....

Comment: Oh ok I thought it was possible to do this in one line by using array_search or something else... my bad

Comment: Actually you can do it in one line I think

Comment: Related:  [Filter 2d array to keep all rows which contain a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50095557/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this inside getSectionByValue function if you really want an one liner.

```
return key(array_filter($sections, fn($section) => in_array($value, $section)));
```

If the provided value exists in multiple sections, it will just return the first one.

Comment: This is not optimized for performance because `array_filter()` does not have the capacity to `break` as soon as a qualifying match is found.